# Full vs. Partial mediation - drawing conclusions from null effects?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mediation

From day 1 in frequentist statistics classes, they teach you, "you can't drawn inferences from null effects". And yet isn't that exactly what we're doing when we distinguish between full and partial mediation? Because the "a" variable effect on "c" has become non-significant, we infer that "a" is not related to "c" (conditional on the mediator). How is this okay?

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by meditation?

Comment: @kevin012 please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics) or see Baron & Kenny, 1986

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not okay since the "non-significance" could just be due to low statistical power. If it makes you feel any better, many authors have argued that we should abandon the Baron & Kenny steps and avoid using terms like full vs. partial mediation. Instead statistical testing of the indirect effect is advocated. For example:

- Zhao, X., Lynch Jr, J. G., & Chen, Q. (2010). Reconsidering Baron and Kenny: Myths and truths about mediation analysis. Journal of consumer research, 37(2), 197-206.